# Does backing up Azure API Management service take the service down during the backup process at all?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-api-management

I'm wondering what implications ,if any, backing up a production API Management Service has on production traffic. The reason for me asking is that I recently tested running the backup cmdlet

```
Backup-AzApiManagement ..
```

and during the process ( which took anywhere between 15-25 minutes), within the Azure Portal on the main APIMS page for the service I was backing up, it stated "Updating service..."

I just want to be sure I understand if there are any potential downtime that need to be accounted for during the backup. Perhaps I need to run the backup during non-peak hours if so. I would hate to run the backup operation during peak hours, just unaware of potential downtime just to kick myself later when I find out that the service is expected to be down intermittently during the backup operation.

Any insight is appreciated. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no downtime if you are within the same region, however if its different region If you use the same Use the same API Management instance name there will be a [`downtime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-migrate#option-2-use-the-same-api-management-instance-name).

Comment: Sorry, can you read your answer again just to make sure it has a little more clarity? It’s almost the exact answer?

Answer (score 0):

There will be no downtime. The API's is still working even when doing backup. However the developer portal is locked for editing. (I have tested running queries against API's when doing backup)

The only downside is that the APIM also throws an event in the Resource health log. Which means that if you have alerts configured for you APIM there will be an alert every time you are running a backup! I am digging for a solution for this, thats why I ended up here.

Comment: Well after some testing, it seems that above text only applies to the Developer Tier for the API managment. Premium tier seems to be working as expexted in terms of the service health alert issue.